# Showing that a function is harmonic

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions, conformal-geometry, elliptic-equations, potential-theory

Suppose that $\phi: \mathbb D \to \Omega $ is a conformal map from the unit circle to a Jordan domain $\Omega$. Fix a point $e ^{i \theta} \in \mathbb D  $, how  I can show that function $u: \mathbb D \to \mathbb D$, which $u(z)= \arg ( \frac{\phi (z)-\phi(e^{i \theta})}{z-e^{i \theta}} ) $ is harmonic?

I can not prove this directly, for example by showing that $\triangle u =0$.

The fact that $u$ is harmonic is used in proof of Theorem II.4.2 of Garnett and Marshall's Harmonic measure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function $(\phi(z)-\phi(e^{i\theta}))/(z-e^{i\theta})$ is holomorphic and non-vanishing  in $\Bbb D$: since the disk is simply connected it has a holomorphic logarithm. $\arg(w)$ is the imaginary part of $\log(w)$.

(If $w=re^{it}$ then $log(w)=\log(r)+it$.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am begginer in complex analysis and PDE. I learnt from your answer how to look at things!  https://stackexchange.com/users/6468444/david-c-ullrich

Comment: I check now site on android and can not mention people. Thanks anyway.